# Sending Mp4 Video to PHP server via ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ftp, asiformdatarequest

Here I am sending the file path or file with some parameters. But the server didn't get the video. So any problem in that code? Or anything you want to add something. Then please tell me.  Any delegate method you want to tell me where I get error or setting in response .

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hangover" ofType:@"mp4"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://156.75.28.172:52/aircas/RestServices/fileUpload"]];

[request setPostValue:filename forKey:@"name"]; 

[request setPostValue:@"GUnit" forKey:@"title"];
[request setPostValue:@"133" forKey:@"user_id"]; 
[request setPostValue:@"8953d0e1c97ef83c9f0aff47" forKey:@"token"]; 
[request setPostValue:@"video song" forKey:@"desc"]; 
[request setPostValue:@"34" forKey:@"video_id"]; 
[request setPostValue:@"0" forKey:@"is_private"]; 

[request setFile:path forKey:@"video"];

[request setTimeOutSeconds:500]; 
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request startSynchronous];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hangover" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSData *movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://156.75.28.172:52/aircas/RestServices/fileUpload"]];

     [request setPostValue:filename forKey:@"name"]; 

    [request setPostValue:@"GUnit" forKey:@"title"];
     [request setPostValue:@"133" forKey:@"user_id"]; 
     [request setPostValue:@"8953d0e1c97ef83c9f0aff47" forKey:@"token"]; 
     [request setPostValue:@"video song" forKey:@"desc"]; 
    [request setPostValue:@"34" forKey:@"video_id"]; 
    [request setPostValue:@"0" forKey:@"is_private"]; 

    [self.request setData:movieData withFileName:@"hangover.mp4" andContentType:@"multipart/form-data" forKey:@"video"];

    [request setTimeOutSeconds:500]; 
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request startSynchronous];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanx for the answer but is there any content type for setFile. because server wants just file not data.. so can you tell me that

Comment: You can use this...[self.request setFile:path withFileName:@"hangover.mp4" andContentType:@"multipart/form-data" forKey:@"video"];

Comment: how to fetch response in - (void) uploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request { //Upload failed; }

Comment: NSLog(@"Response ====>%@",[request responseString]);

Answer (score 5):

Add following code in your code and than you can write 2 delegate methods and can handle response.

```
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];

- (void) uploadFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    //Upload succeeded;
}

- (void) uploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    //Upload failed;
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error Description-->%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

To have indepth view for ASIHttpRequest [please see documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). Its very well documented.

Comment: without that ... my code is ok or not.. do i need to write content type

Comment: how to fetch response in 
- (void) uploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{
    //Upload failed;
       
}